# How can I prevent googletest from swallowing stdout (std::cout) from my code under test?

Tags: c++, googletest

I have a test that's failing, and the code under test will have emitted diagnostics to std::cout before it failed.

However, googletest swallows my code's std::cout, showing its 'RUN..OK ladder-like' report summary.

I don't want my test to capture and assert std::cout, which I believe is possible...

I'd like a mechanism (command line flag to gtest_main?) that stops it from swallowing my code's std::cout temporarily so I can see what's happening.

Is this possible? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am pretty sure whatever you `cout` will appear in your console when running a gtest. There is no need to do anything.

Comment: I confirm ... mine are showing correctly

Comment: Thank you, Davide and Gojita, you're right - I'm mistaken.I'm using a lightweight logging abstraction that has a configurable log level threshold, which by default is 'info' - and the code under test was logging at 'debug' level, so nothing was being output. I've set the threshold to 'debug' in my test, now I see the output. Thank you for your responses!